# Is there any python-Dataframe function in which I can iterate over rows of certain columns?

Tags: python-3.x

Want to solve this kind of problem in python:

```
tran_df['bad_debt']=train_df.frame_apply(lambda x: 1 if (x['second_mortgage']!=0 and x['home_equity']!=0) else x['debt'])
```

I want be able to create a new column and iterate over index row for specific columns.

in excel it's really easy I did:

```
if(AND(col_name1<>0,col_name2<>0),1,col_name5)
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over rows only for certain columns:

```
for rowIndex, row in df[['col1','col2']].iterrows(): #iterate over rows
```

To create a new column:

```
df['new'] = 0  # Initialise as 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, iterating over rows in pandas is wrong. Use the `np.where` function from NumPy to select the right values for the rows:

```
tran_df['bad_debt'] = np.where(
         (tran_df['second_mortgage'] != 0) & (tran_df['home_equity'] != 0),
         1, tran_df['debt'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First to create a new column with initial value, then to use .loc to locate rows that match certain condition and assign new value:

```
tran_df['bad_debt']=tran_df['debt']
tran_df.loc[(tran_df['second_mortgage']!=0)&(tran_df['home_equity']!=0),'bad_debt']=1
```

Or

```
tran_df['bad_debt']=1
tran_df.loc[(tran_df['second_mortgage']==0)|(tran_df['home_equity']==0),'bad_debt']=tran_df['debt']
```

Remember to put round brackets for each condition between bitwise operators (& |)